# Запрет по странам без GEOIP

Tags: php

Как можно запретить страны, которые обращается пользователь. `GeoIP` нет на хостинге.

Comment: Заведите geoip, очевидно же.

Comment: может можно откуда то парсить?

Answer (score 1):

[База данных](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz)

[PHP модуль](http://pecl.php.net/get/geoip-1.0.8.tgz)

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать парсить из хедера Accept-Language.

Answer (score 1):

Все проще.

```
$api_ip = "http://ru.smart-ip.net/geoip-json?host=$Ip&lang=en";
$apis = json_decode(@file_get_contents($api_ip));
$country = $apis->countryCode;
```

Comment: Ну это пока/если на `smart-ip.net` не забанят за коммерческое использование.

Answer (score 0):

Найти в нете базу стран-айпи. загнать к себе в базу, и проверять. если требуется запрет по определённым странам то проще загнать требуемые диапазоны в блек лист в файле .htacces